# Is this a comminuted fracture?

Tags: orthopedics, bone-fractures, fibula, tibia, x-rays

It says online that a fracture with multiple segments is considered comminuted, but in the case below with one tibial and two fibular segments, im not sure if there's enough segments to warrant calling it comminuted. [image]

Comment: Three segments in the tib and four in the fib. Seems like plenty

Comment: Some of these radiographs are obviously comminuted. Those that arent might also be, from experience, intraoperative findings of comminuted fractures are common in patients with simple fractures as seen in their xrays.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say no because I was under the impression there was also a component of the fragment sizes in the definition (I'm not a specialist), but in doing a bit of research I appear to be wrong.

I was going to say originally it's a seemingly-open leg fracture (both bones), but according to http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00522 it is conminuted, i.e.

> Comminuted fracture: This type of fracture is very unstable. The bone shatters into three or more pieces.